# Template deduction of return type

Tags: c++

I have a function that will retry a function for a certain number of times and return whether it was successful:

```
template<typename Functor>
bool Attempt(Functor functor)
{
    bool success = false;
    size_t retries = MAX_RETRIES;
    do
    {
         success = functor();
    }
    while (!success && retries-- > 0);
    return success;
}

// usage:
bool success = Attempt([=]() {
    return something_that_may_not_work_the_first_time();
});
```

This works fine and is used through out the code where I need to retry something a multiple number of times (serial comms for example).

However I have recently needed to `Attempt` something that returns a `std::optional<>`.

What I came up with is this:

```
template <typename T, typename Functor>
std::optional<T> Attempt(Functor functor)
{
    std::optional<T> success{};
    size_t Retries = MAX_VALIDATION_RETRIES;
    do
    {
        success = functor();
    }
    while (!success && Retries-- > 0);
    return success;
}

// usage
std::optional<unsigned int> response = Attempt<unsigned int>([=]() {
    return something_that_returns_optional_unsigned_int();
});
```

Which works but is unsightly having the `<unsigned int>` on both sides of the assignment operator.

Is there any template chicanery that can be added to deduce that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the types you specify explicitly can be deduced:

```
#include <optional>

template <typename Functor>
auto Attempt(Functor functor)
{
    decltype(functor()) success{};
    size_t Retries = 42;
    do
    {
        success = functor();
    }
    while (!success && Retries-- > 0);
    return success;
}

std::optional<unsigned int> something_that_returns_optional_unsigned_int() { return {};};

int main() {
    auto response = Attempt([]{ return something_that_returns_optional_unsigned_int(); });
}
```

Comment: That fails to compile when the `bool` version of Attempt is present.  It gives the error `ambiguous call to overloaded function`.  I think I should of specified that I also still need to call the simple bool version.

Comment: @graham.reeds do you actually need both overloads? They are doing the exact same thing, no?

Comment: There are functions that do not have a response associated with them.  The bool attempt says that yes the information was transmitted to the remote device or no, the information was not.  In the case of the optional<> version is when there is a return value from the remote device that is needed.  Failure in this case can be that the information was unable to leave the local machine; no response was received from the remote device or response was 0 bytes. Logging with in the function reveals what was the ultimate cause of the failure.

Comment: @graham.reeds sorry I dont understand what you mean. When I look at your original `Attempt` then it is exactly the same code as the one that works for `std::optional` in my answer. The ony difference is `bool success = false;` otherwise it is literally the same code. And when `fuctor` returns a `bool` then `decltype(functor()) success{};` is ok too